# Parameterized SQL : Insert not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do `INSERT` using parameterized SQL. I'm new to parameterized SQL. My table name is `archpedia.full_developers (db.table)`

My connection is also working perfectly. I've created custom user with only `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE` privilege on my database archpedia. I even checked the `SQL` with root just to confirm whether there was some error with user privilege but even root doesn't seem to work.

Here is my php :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO full_developers (fullname, username, email, password, project, phone, token, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    echo "ok?";
    if ($insert_stmt) {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('sssssiss', $fullname, $username, $email, $password, $project, $phone, $uniqueToken, $random_salt);
        //$insert_stmt->execute();
        // Execute the prepared query.
        echo "check";
        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
            header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
        }
    }
    //header('Location: ./register_success.php');
```

Well my error is that `$insert_stmt->prepape($query);` doesn't work. I don't get any errors. When I put in statement echo "check" to see weather `$insert_stmt` is working or not, it is never displayed. I'm unable to know where exactly I'm doing wrong hence any help would be grateful.

Comment: You're attempting to insert 8 values but you only have seven placeholders in your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first if you have 8 values (missing one more)

```
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

add 8 placeholders for 8 values

```
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**On error reporting** to check further error

Comment: Thanks man. Damn how could I've missed such a silly thing. Maybe in haste.

Answer (score 2):

$query = "INSERT INTO full_developers (fullname, username, email, password, project, phone, token, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)";

/*replace your query with this.*/